# how retrieve sum of multiple column ? codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a table sales_items ,where we save all sales item with all details -my table is :

---

```
sales_id  | sales item| No.ofpacks |   quantity(liters pr pack) | 
---------     ----------- ------------   ---------------- 
   31           petrol        2               2.5
   31           disel de2     3               3.2
   34           petrol se     2               4.2
   31           castrol       7               4.1
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

now we want total number of liters at any one sales_id , means if we take sales_id 31 , then we want total `liters =(2*2.5) + (3*3.2) +(7*7.2),`  i search but not found any suitable help on google .
we try :

```
public function total_liter($id) {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('sale_items', array('sale_id' => $id), 1);
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach($q as $row):

            $total_liter += $row['no_of_packs']*$row['quantity'];
            endforeach;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure they are your real column names ?

Comment: no no ..its demo ..i want only concept

Comment: Is the method you wrote not giving the required result? The logic seems to be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing this using `mysql`

```
SELECT SUM(quantity * no_of_packs) as total FROM table_name WHERE sales_id = 31
```

Here is CI flavor,

```
$this->db->select('SUM(quantity * no_of_packs) as total', false);
$this->db->from('table_name');
$this->db->where('sales_id', 31);
```

Note that second argument in select will prevent CI from adding unnecessary backticks.

Comment: but how can we assign it's value in any variable , by which we can save in database means can we use , $total=SELECT SUM(quantity * no_of_packs) as total FROM table_name WHERE sales_id = 31 ;

Comment: what does IMHO stand for?

Comment: by using variable instead 31, like `"sales_id = $id"` or `$this->db->where('sales_id', $id);` in CI where `$id` should be defined before query

Comment: People need to stop using stupid acronyms, no offense to you. Or should I say NOTY?

Comment: how about now ? :) @CodeGodie

Comment: Awesome. That calmed me down :) Thanks.